# Closing Workbook after opening it through VBA - Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code below. I've called the excel document from a VBA code. However, after pressing the closing button on the workbook, it doesn't close until I stop the macro. I want to be able to close the document without stopping the macro. i.e. the main userform is still running behind. I can close the excel workbook from the close button top right of the workbook itself.

Anyone happen to know how to solve this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()
  Workbooks("master system.xlsm").Activate
  Workbooks.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Toolbox\Define\PPST.xlsx"

End Sub
```

Comment: It may help if you state what you want to achieve/why....

Answer (score 0):

Try `Workbooks("PPST.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True`

This is from the documentation [enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-close-method-excel)

Comment: Tried doing that. It closes the workbook immediately. 

What I want to do is to close the work book, after using it, manually from the close button. Would you happen to have another code for it? 

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try scattering `DoEvents` throughout your code after opening the workbook.

Just be aware that if you depend on the `ActiveWorkbook` or `Selection` objects in your code, they **could** change after `DoEvents`.

`DoEvents` essentially tells your code to pause, and let Excel do other, waiting tasks -- such as allowing the user to select cells, and probably closing a workbook -- before continuing.